# How i can read google analytics data from my iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I am trying to read google analytics data for sessions and real time users , locations ... from my iPhone Objective-c App

is there any SDK can achieve this or maybe REST API from google ?

Comment: I do not think you can use GoogleAnalytics for that. But you can use Apple's. They are in iTunesConnect under *AppAnalytics*

Answer (score 0):

you can build REST API in your favourite language and use that in your iPhone app.